# How to diagnose "ImportError: cannot import name"

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

I am looking for a systematic approach to dealing with "cannot import name" errors in python. I would like to know

1. what are all of the situations that generate this message
2. what can be done to determine the cause of the error.

I know cyclic imports are a common cause, but there seem to be others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback is the one way to determine if an import is cyclical.

The other possibility is that the name doesn't exist in the imported module. You either misspelled the name, or you imported a *different* module from what you expected. Diagnose by running:

```
import module
print module.__file__
```

to check if you got the right module. Use `dir(module)` to check what names it defines.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up for me. I think my confusion came from the myriad ways one might accidentally import the wrong module.